# PrometheusMeterRegistry stuck at scrape function call

Tags: micrometer

Im having a problem configuring a PrometheusMeterRegistry to get metrics from a Geode cluster.
After configuring the endpoint, if I run curl command to check if the metrics are available at the configured endpoint, the http request handler gets stuck at the scrape function:

```
    public void start(MetricsSession session) {
        this.session = session;
        registry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
        this.session.addSubregistry(registry);

        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(9000);
        httpServer = null;
        try {
            httpServer = HttpServer.create(address, 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpContext context = httpServer.createContext("/metrics");
        context.setHandler(this::requestHandler);
        httpServer.start();
    }

    private void requestHandler(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        final byte[] scrapeBytes = registry.scrape().getBytes();
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, scrapeBytes.length);
        final OutputStream responseBody = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        responseBody.write(scrapeBytes);
        responseBody.close();
    }
```

As you can see, this code mainly the same as the example of how to configure Prometheus registry in https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus

But if I execute `curl http://localhost:9000/metrics/` I get no answer. I have checked that the problem comes from the `registry.scrape()` call, it gets stuck.

Any clue about what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: One update: I tried commenting the line that adds the PrometheusMeterRegistry to the MetricsSession, and created a counter. The result is the same. I think this discards that Geode code is involved as in this case the registry is not receiving metrics from Geode.

Comment: New update: I implemented a simple program with a PrometheusMeterRegistry, and the curl command works. So maybe the problem is in the Geode integration with Micrometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Not sure about the reason, but after packing the dependencies of my code in the same jar (instead of adding all the jars to classpath), I finally got an answer from the endpoint.